# How can I disable USB removable devices except mouse and keyboard

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive

I am the owner of a small company (4 employees) and I have Win 7 Ultimate on my machine. My other PCs are connected via LAN and they too have Windows 7 on their machine. My question is, is there any way to prevent USB storage devices. Recently I found one of the employee cheating on me and found he is taking away some important projects which he has access too. I'd like to prevent that.

I read some tricks about changing values in registry but those are just *tricks*. Changing it's value back again would bring back the USB access. I need some genuine way to prevent access to USB. Only me when logged in as Administrator account should be able to access USB storage devices.

Comment: There's physical locks for USB devices - might be a nice, OS agnostic way to prevent people from misusing USB use

Comment: The tool to prevent the problem you're highlighting is called "Attorney" - Every company should have one. Beyond that do what [Journeyman Geek](http://serverfault.com/questions/541730/how-can-i-disable-usb-removable-devices-except-mouse-and-keyboard#comment623763_541730) suggested, or what the DoD does (shoot epoxy into all the USB ports)

Comment: Symantec AV allows you to do this...other AV's may as well.

Comment: You should almost certainly block network access as well. They could copy files to The Cloud when you're not looking.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use a group policy. Please see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b08a4d76-d639-49ae-9e4c-2a5aacfd8c7a/how-to-create-group-policy-to-disable-usb-access-to-users ; the second answer tells you how to disable USB storage devices.

You will need to whitelist the devices you want while disabling everything else.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731387(WS.10).aspx